# How to install git server on debian VPS (openvz+direct admin)?

Tags: debian, vps, git, openvz

What are the risks and precaution steps when installing git server on debian VPS (openvz + direct admin) ? How to install git server properly in such environment ?

I would like to use git server (such as http://git-scm.com/) to manage source code version control centrally.

Comment: Rather than apt-get what you need and getting possibly incompatible versions of libs in your `/usr/local` tree, I would recommend recompiling everything you need for git in a dedicated directory: https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GIT alone is usually not sufficient to handle a bunch of repository with different ACLs.
Take a look at third-party solutions like Gitosis or Gitolite.

http://blog.philippklaus.de/2011/06/install-gitosis-on-debian-squeeze/

On our development server we use Debian Squeeze with gitosis+redmine (apt-get install gitosis redmine).

You can also use a more comprehensive solution like Gitorius, but isn't so easy to install.